# Set width of module table to the width of the module

Tags: module, custom-module

I use the module `Display News` with the custom class `dn` on my home page to display the last articles published. The width of the module adjusted to the size of the screen but only if the screen is wider than 410px. So on smartphone with a screen of 320px, the text in the module is cut.

[image]

I've found a temporary work around but by setting the width of `blogdn` width the rule @media.

```
@media (max-width: 410px) { 

.blogdn {
width:270px;
    }
}
```

But I have to set 5 different `max-width` with `@media` to prevent the text from being cut for all screen width possible between 320px and 410px. Because this isn't a very nice fix I am trying to find something else.

I've tried tried several approach, adding `position relative` to the parent `div`, or adding `display: block; overflow: hidden`; but without success.

Also there is something strange: on the French version of the website, the module is cut when the screen width is 400px but not on the English version. Couldn't find why.

EDIT: This work around seems to work better than the @media one, thanks Lodder!

```
.moduletabledn{
display: block;
overflow: hidden;
    }

.moduletabledn tbody{
display: block;
overflow: hidden;
    }   

.moduletabledn tr{
display: block;
overflow: hidden;
    }   
.moduletabledn td{
display: block;
overflow: hidden;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing I would do is make the images 100% width and use `display:block;` for mobiles. Text should not wrap around images on mobiles as long words can push the child element outside of the parent.

Id also suggest you use 100% width rather than specific pixels for the `blogdn` class.

You also have a margin and padding being set on the `megamod` which is pushing the content.

You may want to look into the [Box Sizing](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp) property is you're going to be using paddings and margins

Comment: Thanks a lot Lodder for the image style on mobile, it looks better that way!  I have tried setting `width:100%` for `blogdn` but without success. Even if I remove the `padding/margin` on megamod, the problem still remains. To me, the problem seems to be on the table used by DisplayNews. The table has the class `moduletabledn`. I could set the table width to the same width than the div `megamod` but not the `tbody`.

Comment: Well, thanks to you, I've found another work around: not sure it's best one but still it's better than @media + fix width. Please have a look at the edit in my question. It's  based on the table.

Comment: @Enora - Looking much better now. I would also add the following to your CSS file: `.item.column-1 > a { display: inline-block; }` which will push the tags and category below the image if there's no or little content. You'll see what I mean on the `Finding the courage to question...` section

Comment: Thanks a lot Lodder for your extra work!  I've added .blogdn .item.column-1 > a {display: inline-block;} just to make sure this won't affect the rest of the website. I'm happy it's fixed!